# InfoPath - How can I read a people picker field and query AD to load additional fields related to the person in the field.

Tags: infopath

How can I read a people picker field and query AD to load additional fields related to the person in the field. Example: Employee Name; load information want to load email address, phone number. the InfoPath form is being used with Nintex Workflow and SharePoint 2010.

I have searched and have not been able to find answer.

Thanks
D

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation points yet to leave a comment, but your question really doesn't provide enough detail. So any answer provided is going to be based on assumptions. You don't even clarify what version of InfoPath you're using.

That said, a good place to start is to create a data connection to receive data. You'll need to select the web service option and will then need to enter in the web server address. The address will probably be in the following format:

http://yourservernamehere/_vti_bin/userprofileservice.asmx?wsdl

Replace yourservernamehere with the address of your SharePoint server. Then, you'll need to select GetUserProfileByName as the operation you need. Just keep on clicking next and then finish to complete the connection.

You will then have to view the data source within InfoPath to see what fields are available and map the ones you want to the fields you want prepopulated on your form.

All this is based on my own assumptions, so I can't guarantee it will work in your scenario. Happy to assist if you still need help and are able to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

To autocomplete you can use your e-mail or phone number fields, with a new action rule. This is due to people picker fields not allowing any action rules applied to them.

The web service option mentioned in another answer unfortunately no longer works in SharePoint Online. Please use a data connection the hidden User Information List located on the stem of your SharePoint site instead.

Condition:

- Use the condition DisplayName is not blank by using "Select a field or group..." in advanced view and selecting your people pickers DisplayName field

Actions:

- Set a field's value

  - Field: User Information List data connection queryFields DisplayName of people picker
  - Value: your forms DisplayName of people picker
- Query using a data connection: User Information List data connection
- Set a field's value

  - Field: your forms email or phone number field
  - Value: data fields > Work_email / Work_phone of your data connection